# Youtube API V3 ETag support fail: content not change but etag change

Tags: php, youtube-data-api, etag

I send a "playlistItems" request with this headers:

```
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(29) "Content-Type:application/json"
    [1]=>
    string(153) "Authorization:Bearer [hidden]"
    [2]=>
    string(33) "X-JavaScript-User-Agent:Automator"
    [3]=>
    string(66) "If-Match:"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/AtpZMDGfwUXtVHbcH_1spJYn8eg""
    [4]=>
    string(71) "If-None-Match:"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/AtpZMDGfwUXtVHbcH_1spJYn8eg""
  }
```

The url is: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id%2Csnippet&playlistId=UUvmF_tzu-eK6FRfMlOp6-Fg

But i receive a ETag diferent without the content change.

Youtube V3 really support ETag? or headers are wrong?

I do not use any oficial library. My code uses PHP and Curl.

```
$this->execute(
        "playlistItems",
        array("part"=>"id,snippet","playlistId"=>$channelId)
        ,$etag
    );
```

And

```
public function execute($source, $options, $etag = null)
{
    if (count($options)==0) {
        $url=$this->base_url.$source;
    } else {
        $vars=array();
        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            $vars[]=$key."=".urlencode($value);
        }
        $vars=implode("&", $vars);
        $url=$this->base_url.$source."?".$vars;
    }

    $httpheader=array(
        'Content-Type'=>'application/json',
        'Authorization'=>'Bearer ' . $this->token,
        'X-JavaScript-User-Agent'=>'Automator'
        );
    if ($etag!=null) {
        $httpheader["If-Match"]='"'.$etag.'"';
        $httpheader["If-None-Match"]='"'.$etag.'"';
    }

    $client=new \Conect\Request();
    $request=$client->get($url, array("headers"=>$httpheader));
    $this->etag="";
    if (array_key_exists("ETag", $request->headers_out)) {
        $this->etag=$request->headers_out['ETag'];
    }
    $this->last_request=$request;
    $this->etag=str_replace('"', "", $this->etag);
    $this->etag=trim($this->etag);
    if ($request->code==304) {
        throw new ExceptionNoChange("No changes");
    }
    return $this->response($request->data);
}
```

Section of "\Conect\Request"

```
if (array_key_exists("headers", $options)) {
    $headers_in=array();
    foreach ($options['headers'] as $key => $value) {
        $headers_in[]=$key.":".$value."";
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers_in);
    $this->headers_in=$headers_in;
}
```

**Action**: I sent a request with a ETag
**Expect**: Http code 304
**Result**: Http 200 with a new ETag.

Comment: can you [edit] your question with the code you're using? - for clarification purposes, what is the full requierement?. Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: done. Added parts of my code.